# Query Optimisation - UNION

Tags: sql, performance, union

I use the below query to get data from 3 tables , SOURCE1,SOURCE2,SOURCE3 which needs to be inserted into another table FINAL.I would like to know whether the below query can be further tuned.

```
SELECT s3.unit ,s2.col1,s2.col2, '00-1' dest  
FROM source1 s1   
INNER JOIN source2 s2 ON s1.altunit = s2.unit  
INNER JOIN source3 s3 ON s1.unit = s3.unit   
WHERE sysdate BETWEEN s1.e_date AND  s1.d_date   
AND s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1)  

UNION  

SELECT s3.price,s2.col1,s2.col2, '00-1' dest  
FROM source1 s1   
INNER JOIN source2 s2 ON s1.altunit = s2.unit  
INNER JOIN source3 s3 ON s1.unit = s3.unit   
WHERE sysdate BETWEEN s1.e_date AND  s1.d_date   
AND s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1) 

UNION  

SELECT s3.price,s2.col1,s2.col2, s2.dest  
FROM source1 s1   
INNER JOIN source2 s2 ON s1.altunit = s2.unit  
INNER JOIN source3 s3 ON s1.unit = s3.unit   
WHERE sysdate BETWEEN s1.e_date AND  s1.d_date   
AND s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1)  

UNION

SELECT s3.cost,s2.col1,s2.col2, s2.dest  
FROM source1 s1   
INNER JOIN source2 s2 ON s1.altunit = s2.unit  
INNER JOIN source3 s3 ON s1.unit = s3.unit   
WHERE sysdate BETWEEN s1.e_date AND  s1.d_date   
AND s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1)
```

Comment: You are repeating `(SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1)` every single query. You should prefetch this data before running queries to merge.

Comment: What's even the difference? I can't spot it.

Comment: Only the data in the 1st postion of the SELECT statement varies. Remaining conditions - JOIN and WHERE clause remains the same

Comment: What DBMS are you using? If it supports CTE it should be easy to optimize, LATERAL or CROSS APPLY would also make it easy to improve things

Comment: @Lennart  I use Oracle 10.2.0 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Only the data in the 1st position of the SELECT statement varies. Remaining conditions - JOIN and WHERE clause remain the same. We just need to emit 4 rows for every 1 row we selected:

```
SELECT variants.*
FROM source1 s1
INNER JOIN source2 s2 ON s1.altunit = s2.unit
INNER JOIN source3 s3 ON s1.unit = s3.unit
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT s3.unit ,s2.col1,s2.col2, '00-1' dest UNION
    SELECT s3.price,s2.col1,s2.col2, '00-1' dest UNION
    SELECT s3.price,s2.col1,s2.col2, s2.dest UNION
    SELECT s3.cost,s2.col1,s2.col2, s2.dest
) variants
WHERE sysdate BETWEEN s1.e_date AND s1.d_date
AND s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1)
```

Comment: I want to use UNION as there should not be any duplicate rows.

Comment: There you go. Was easy enough to adapt.

Comment: If not, Oracle surely has an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Google tells me that Oracle 10 supports CTE, if it's true you could do like:

```
with tmp (unit, price, cost, col1, col2, dest1, dest2) as (
    SELECT s3.unit, s3.price, s3.cost, s2.col1, s2.col2, s2.dest, '00-1'  
    FROM source1 s1   
    JOIN source2 s2 
        ON s1.altunit = s2.unit  
    JOIN source3 s3 
        ON s1.unit = s3.unit   
    WHERE sysdate BETWEEN s1.e_date AND  s1.d_date   
      AND s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1)
)
select unit, col1, col2, dest2 from tmp  
union
select price, col1, col2, dest2 from tmp    
union
select price, col1, col2, dest1 from tmp  
union
select cost, col1, col2, dest1 from tmp
```

I assume that Oracle will evaluate it in a more efficient way than your original query.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, all four subqueries are the same except for the `select`.  Often, the fastest approach is to unpivot the data by using a `cross join` and conditional logic:

```
SELECT (case when n.n = 1 then s3.unit
             when n.n in (2, 3) then s3.price
             when n.n = 4 then s3.cost
        end) as unit,
       s2.col1, s2.col2,
       (case when n.n in (1, 2) then '00-1'
             when n.n in (3, 4) then s2.dest
        end) as dest  
FROM source1 s1 INNER JOIN
     source2 s2
     ON s1.altunit = s2.unit INNER JOIN
     source3 s3
     ON s1.unit = s3.unit CROSS JOIN
     (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual union all select 3 from dual union all select 4 from dual
     ) n 
WHERE sysdate BETWEEN s1.e_date AND  s1.d_date   
AND s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1);
```

If you still need to eliminate duplicates, then use `select distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

`CROSS APPLY` is the way to do it, as *@usr* suggested.
I would just add that `AND s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1)` can be a performance killer.
It depends on how many different "unit" you can have :

- If `SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1` returns like 4 values, keep it like this.
- If it returns more than 40 values, just use an `INNER JOIN` instead :

Original :

```
FROM source1 s1   
    [...]
WHERE
    s1.unit IN (SELECT unit FROM source1 WHERE u_sw = 1)
```

To :

```
FROM source1 s1   
    INNER JOIN source1 s1limit 
        ON s1limit.unit = s1.unit 
        AND s1limit.u_sw = 1
```